# Authorize ARB subscription payment

Tags: php, authorize.net

I am creating a subscription using Authorize.net ARB API. I can see in my account, where the subscription is created.

Its a very simple subscription, where a user would be paying $100 every month. I would like to know, if the user would be billed at the time of creation of the subscription ?

My understanding is that, he would be billed only from next month ? Any idea, how to bill the customer from the time the subscription is created ?

Thanks

Comment: @munya, @john-conde Could anybody advice on how it works now? The answers described here use deprecated methods. If I have the start date set to 2 mins from `now()` when creating a subscription? Will the payment be processed in 2 minutes or do they happen in a specific time of the day?

Answer (score 1):

ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest has parameter "startDate" where you can set date the subscription begins.
If first price should be different from monthly payments you can also set parameter "trialAmount" for first payment

All information you can find here
http://www.authorize.net/support/ARB_guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You should *always* charge the first subscription payment using the [AIM API](http://developer.authorize.net/api/aim/). The AIM API will process immediately and act as a verification for the credit card. You will know **immediately** if a card is invalid and before you create the subscription. If you schedule a payment to process the same day the subscription is created it does not process immediately. That process later that night. If the credit card is invalid you lose the opportunity to have the user correct it because they are no longer present at your website.